# JSP generating .xml file

Tags: java, xml, jsp, struts

I have a JSP file that generates an XML file. Let's say its name is `foo.jsp`. The XML generation is working well.

Nonetheless, the users access the file by hitting

`myserver/foo.do`

So, I need a way to make it

`myserver/foo.xml`

Comment: A JSP has no reason to generate an XML file. Perform that logic in your struts controller/servlet.

Comment: Is there any reason you could not do this with `mod_rewrite`?

Comment: @thatidiotguy I don't have access to apache's files. Sotirios how can I do it? Pleas, advice.

Comment: Do you want your users to download the xml file?

Comment: What about [htaccess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess)?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis it should be readable by google crawlers (it's a news sitemap). The content is rendering on the page. I'd just like it to have .xml as extension, instead of .do. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that with struts (unless there's some static resource mapping). You can write your own servlet to offer up xml files.

Comment: @BackSlash unfortunately, modifications to apache are out of the question. Thanks!

Comment: this is not a modification to apache, htaccess is a file that you place in the server root folder i.e. `/web/htdocs/www`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while I'm disagree with generating xml with jsp but you can add this section inside web-app(tag) in your web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>JspXML</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/pages/foo.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JspXML</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/foo.xml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

while you are still can access the xml file by foo.jsp, for preventing that, just put the jsp file in WEB-INF folder